# How to convert a string containing hex to a number?

Tags: hex

I receive a 5 byte hex display from the port com (B00002074c) number on the display 33740 but when I convert it shows this number 132940

Comment: hi! what language are you using? please include as many details as you can when posting a question. thanks!

Comment: I use C # language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert integer to hexadecimal and back again](/q/1139957/90527)